# Why is the ROS wiki dump smaller than a year ago?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was moving my ROS mirror to a different machine, and ran the [update-wiki](http://answers.ros.org/question/10010/create-a-rosorg-wiki-mirror/) script the first time around before cron picks it up.

Now I am sure that back in November 2011, we were at 11GB (and increasing fast), but now we seem to be around 3GB. Specifically, the code api tarball (docs) has gone from 10GB to 1.67GB.

How did this happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57360/why-is-the-ros-wiki-dump-smaller-than-a-year-ago?/) by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2871 on 2013-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the new indexer requiring you to add each repo individually, and the move to github, where 1 stack/meta-package == 1 repo for the most part, I imagine there is a smaller amount of code being indexed.

I know that personally, I used to have a large amount of code in "sandbox" repos which are no longer being indexed.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1